# While loop stopping after one time

Tags: php

Noob alert here. I'm just (trying to) teaching myself PHP because I need it on my internship job. Now I am creating a survey and I am trying to use `while` loops to show the questions and their respective answers onto my XAMPP. I am using this code:

```
  <?php

   mysqli_select_db($conn, "surveyordina");
   //code hier schrijven

   $sql = "SELECT questions_body FROM survey_questions where subthema_id = 1";
   $sql2 = "SELECT answer_body FROM survey_answers where answer_id = 1 or answer_id = 2 or answer_id = 3";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
   $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);



   if(mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0){
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    echo "<br>" ."Vraag: <br>" . $row["questions_body"]. "<br>";

                 while($row_answer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
                              echo  $row_answer["answer_body"]. "<br>";
                           }
                         }
   }

   else{
       echo "No results";
   }
```

Now the returning part of this code looks like this:

> ```
> Vraag: 
> Is the organization aware of where all the personal data is stored? Be it on-site or in the cloud, hosted by the company or by a third party?
> Yes
> No
> I don't know
>
> Vraag: 
> Is the organization able to locate and find personal data of a particular data subject?
>
> Vraag: 
> Does the organization have technology in place to return all personal data on a given data subject, given a single search from personnel?
>
> Vraag: 
> testerino kekkerino
> ```

I am trying to get the *Yes*, *No*, and *I don't know* parts under each and every question but only seem to get it under one of the questions.

Is there a method to return the whole answer part under each question? If so, am I on the right path or am I doing something completely wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `while(mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0)&&($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` instead of having the if seperate from the while. also....with your query are you sure you are supose to get more than 1 result from your database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you hit the end of a result-set, `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` doesn't just keep cycling through.  So you're hitting the end of the `$result2` set within the first outer loop, and then that's it, there are no more results to fetch.

You should fetch all of the `$result2` results outside of the `$result` loop, assign the results to a variable, and then loop through *that* array within the `$result` loop.

Something like:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0){

    $result2Set = mysqli_fetch_all($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<br>" ."Vraag: <br>" . $row["questions_body"]. "<br>";

        foreach($result2Set as $row_answer) {
            echo  $row_answer["answer_body"]. "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing this works! Thank you for the information, now i can continue in my php journey :D!